# Shell script isn't echoing result of command as expected

Tags: bash, shell, rc

I am trying to write a simple shell script, and one aspect of it involves outputting the result of an `lsrc` command. If you aren't familiar with `lsrc`, look here [rcm](http://thoughtbot.github.io/rcm/rcm.7.html)

Here is essentially what I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(lsrc)
echo "$output"
```

all I am seeing is an empty newline, where as running this command in a normal bash/zsh environment prints output to the screen.

Comment: Is `lsrc` depending on some environment variables that aren't set for non-interactive shells?

Comment: What happens if you just run `lsrc` from a script (not from the command line)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. that seems likely, I'm trying to read their man pages but cant find that out.

Comment: @Turn the same thing, no output

Comment: Does `lsrc` print to stdout or to stderr?

Comment: @Zach Can you confirm that `lsrc` in a shell prints stuff, while putting `lsrc` in a file and running the file does not? What does `type lsrc` show in a shell?

Comment: Temporarily add a line after the first, that says "echo $PATH" (without the quotes), or instead add a line "which lsrc".

Comment: @thatotherguy `type lsrc` outputs: `lsrc is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/lsrc` in my shell

Comment: @Roadowl that didn't do much, it just shows me my path and then the location of the lsrc executable

Comment: @Cromax I imagine stdout. `lsrc >&1` and `lsrc >&2` and `lsrc >$(tty)` all work fine.

Comment: @Zach Can you try `o=$(lsrc 2>&1); echo $o`?

Comment: @Cromax no luck :(

Comment: Is the environment variable RCRC available inside your script?

Comment: Re: environment variables: try `env lsrc`. Or just `env` on a line by itself, to see the full environment that `lsrc` is getting.